# how to show flash animation on UIWebview in iPad

Tags: ipad, uiwebview

I am showing an url request on UIWebview in my iPad Application. That url contains some flash animation. It is not appearing on webview or safari in iPad simulator.

Can anyone suggest me that what is the alternative to show the flash animation on UIWebview ?

Answer (score 4):

iPads and iPhones do not support flash.

**You can't view flash on mobile Apple devices.**